# Environment variables not accessible within nodejs script file

Tags: node.js, bash, shell

I have written a shell script as below

```
export MONGO_DBNAME=dev-db
export MONGO_HOST=a.b.c.c.d:27017,w.x.y.z:27017
export MONGO_PORT=27017
export MONGO_USERNAME=devuser
export MONGO_PASSWORD=devpassword
export MONGO_REPLICASET=devreplicaset

babel-node email-report.js
```

the environment variables declared are not accessible within the node script using process.env

Can someone please help with why is this happening and how can it be resolved?

Comment: Add email-report.js to your question.

Answer (score 4):

You can assign it like this also **process.env.BAR = "bar"**

To access in node console this **process.env.BAR** you will get your value **"BAR"**

Answer (score 0):

How are you accessing variable in your JS, its quite simple.

`# ~ export DATA="HELLO"`

```
#  ~ node
> process.env.DATA
'HELLO'
```